# Sync a Sql Server Table with a SharePoint list

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to automatically sync a Sql Server Table with a SharePoint list? (Sql as source and SharePoint as destination).

I tried to connect MS Acces to a SharePoint list as source and seem to work. However now I sould need to sync Sql with Acces... Maybe is there a direct way to link the SharePoint with a Sql DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Business Connectivity Service with an "External List". [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/make-external-list?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656) you will find the steps needed. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-external-content-types-for-sql-server-in-sharepoint?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656) you will find more information about External content types.